# Is there a way to redirect users to a related webpage on your website in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a navbar component and a login component and I want to send the user to the Login page using the navbar link, but it just sends me to the homepage everytime I click Login

```
import React from 'react';
import './Navbar.scss';

class Navbar extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <nav>
                <div className="logo">
                            Travel with Us!
                        </div>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Locations</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./Login.js">Login</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Navbar;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must know that `React` is a `Single Page Application`. We show and hide components in SPA. But page stays the same.

You can use a library which works well with `React` called `react-router-dom` to provide your routes in your application.

This resource may be helpful https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start